# How to write a name as an array, mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
<%int count = 0; %>
<input type="checkbox"  name="Name["'<%count++;%>'"]" />
```

The name isn`t being rendered as expected, it`s being rendered as `name="IssueCreate["''"]" />`

How can I correct that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change `<% %>` to `<%= %>` to output the result of the expression.

Also, why are you using both types of quotes in `IssueCreate["''"]`?